# Integrating Highcharts with REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, highcharts

I'm studying AngularJS and I'm trying to integrate a chart using Highcharts and a REST API.

However, I'm not able to fetch the data:

```
$scope.myData = function() {

  Charts.query({
    id: $scope.currentState.id, 
    name: $scope.currentState.name
  }, 
  function(data) {
    $scope.charts = data;
  });

};

$('#chart').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: $scope.charts.timestamp
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'test'
      }
    },
    series: [{
        data: $scope.charts.value
    }]
});
```

The first part connects to the REST API and the second generates the chart. Currently, I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

Please, can someone help me?

**Update:** full code (http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgrDmKArfxFrMoAEFoTc) and JSON (http://pastebin.com/TX2pLHHe).

Comment: We need to see `data` to help you.

Comment: @Nix This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/yiCnCrbB

Comment: Could you paste the whole error statement?

Comment: @OlatundeGaruba this is the whole error: http://pastebin.com/V2uSiCrk

Comment: I'm looking to see what data is being set `$scope.charts = data;` can you post that json object?

Comment: @Nix this is the json: http://pastebin.com/TX2pLHHe

Comment: Highcharts requires values to be `x` and `y`, not `timestamp` and `value`, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data). Note: `x` (your timestmap) should be number, not a string.

Comment: @superjim is this fixed?  If not can you update this fiddle and cause the issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/0v2m6tsc/

Comment: @Nix thanks for your help. I've posted the full code on Plunker. I think you can have a better view on this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgrDmKArfxFrMoAEFoTc - if I call the data normally, it's displayed there (but not in the charts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs synchronously in the controller however the data is coming in asynchronously. When you call the `$('#chart').highcharts(...)` function your data has not yet arrived so `$scope.charts` is not defined which is why you get a "cannot read 'value' of undefined" error ($scope.charts = undefined, so it has no value property!).

You need to call the highcharts function in the callback of the query. For example (this is untested by the way):

```
$scope.myData = function() {

  Charts.query({
    id: $scope.currentState.id, 
    name: $scope.currentState.name
  }, 
  function(data) {
    $scope.charts = data;
    drawChart(); // <= this is when you invoke the drawing of the chart because data has finally arrived!
  });

};

var drawChart = function(){ 
    $('#chart').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: $scope.charts.timestamp
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'test'
          }
        },
        series: [{
            data: $scope.charts.value
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It removed the errors and it drawn the chart this time. However, it's empty (like it didn't have any data). Any ideas?

Comment: I think there are a few problems in the full source code you posted. Mainly the fact that you are calling `$('#charts').highcharts()` on an interval, I think you are better off calling a redraw of some kind. Any chance you can create a js fiddle with what you have now?

Comment: I would have expected a chart to work in the first call however, unless what you get back in `$scope.charts = data` is actually empty.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll do the jsfiddle. Just one info: if I call this data in another place, it's displayed normally. It's just not displaying in the chart.

Comment: If you definitely have the data then it might just be a case of the structure of it not being compatible with Highcharts so you might need to "massage" it a little. When the fiddle is ready I'll be happy to investigate it a little futher :D

Comment: Sorry for not replying before, I ended up having some issues today. I've posted the code on Plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZgrDmKArfxFrMoAEFoTc/

Comment: The problem in this plunker is 2. First is that there really is no data coming back from the RESTful service (at least for the specified period) so I expanded it to include the last 10 days which does return some data. The second problem is that the data being returned is not directly compatible with Highcharts so you need to modify it a little to work. Here is a working version: http://embed.plnkr.co/8kyFDO2cMNxP0BYZMNs6/

Comment: I would modify it further so that you dont recreate a chart every 10 seconds but only update the data within it. You can follow this from the official Highcharts documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @superjim  if this solved your problem please accept the solution.

Comment: do you know why the chart is loading only after 10s? As I'm calling it on `$scope.init`, it should load with the page, right?

Comment: `$scope.init` really isn't doing anything because it is never called. The chart takes 10 seconds to load because it is only instantiated on the `timer` which runs for the first time 10 seconds after the page load. You can get rid of the `$scope.init` function altogether and simply call `$scope.loadData()` somewhere in the controller. so that on load it triggers the loading/drawing of the data/chart: http://plnkr.co/edit/E0TpEbg3mCQs3wV0RDQF?p=preview

Comment: I got it. Thanks! =)